# c# BackgroundWorker pause

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a small C# application that communicate with a server and get some data via API request, using POST method. It is an Apache server by the way.

My problem is that my C# app sends a tons of requests continuously, and the server creates a tons of log files.

I use a BackgroundWorker and I want to pause it for a few seconds, but Thread.Sleep(5000) doesn't working.

This app is running in the system tray it doesn't have a GUI, just get some content, and print them out.

Code:

```
private void _bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(_config.Prop.server + "content/api.php", "print", "getAll");            

        try
        {
            while (!_bgWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONPrintNeeds needs = parser.DownloadAll();                        
                    List<JSONPrintNeed> temp = new List<JSONPrintNeed>();

                    foreach (JSONPrintNeed need in needs.data)
                    {
                        temp.Add(need);
                    }

                    foreach (JSONPrintNeed need in temp)
                    {
                        Printer printer = new Printer(need.megrendeles);
                        printer.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

                        List<String> installed = new List<String>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
                        {
                            installed.Add(PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i]);
                        }

                        if (installed.Contains(need.nyomtato))
                        {
                            printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = need.nyomtato;
                        }

                        int format = int.Parse(need.format);

                        switch (format)
                        {
                            case 0: 
                            default:            // txt
                                printer.Print();
                                break;
                            case 1:             // html
                                SetDefaultPrinter(need.nyomtato);
                                browser.DocumentText = need.megrendeles;
                                browser.Print();
                                break;
                        }

                        JSONResult result = parser.DeleteOne(int.Parse(need.ny_id));
                    }

                    parser.DeleteAll();
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Expand `Thread.Sleep(5000)` doesnt work

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` doesn't work? How are you making that determination?

Comment: You should read this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287650/send-a-backgroundworker-to-sleep-while-checking-for-cancellation][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287650/send-a-backgroundworker-to-sleep-while-checking-for-cancellation

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EventWaitHandle` for sync threads.

```
EventWaitHandle flag = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset); 
if (stop)
{
    flag.WaitOne(5000);
}
```