# C# BackGroundWorker sleep for x amount of seconds

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a program that puts a task to a bgw, and in that task I want to wait a few seconds before checking for an email, and if not found, wait a few more seconds before checking again.

If I wasn't using a backgroundworker to do this, it would have just been System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x), but how do you accomplish this inside the do_work function of a backgroundworker?

Comment: Why not just launch the task via a timer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)`.  Why wouldn't you use that for a BackgroundWorker?

EDIT: Thanks to cyrianox for answering my question above.  The answer may be found in the accepted answer to the following question:

[Send a backgroundworker to sleep while checking for cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287650/send-a-backgroundworker-to-sleep-while-checking-for-cancellation)

Comment: sleeps the current tread... `Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10))` (as in just use Sleep)

Comment: @PaulKohler it seems to me that the OP wants to sleep the current thread.  But why use Task.Run?  BackgroundWorker doesn't use task-based asynchrony.

Comment: thats just an example of using sleep in a task, i got the impression they thought the were not supposed to do it

Comment: bad idea. see validated answer for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287650/send-a-backgroundworker-to-sleep-while-checking-for-cancellation

Comment: @cyrianox thank you for answering my question "why wouldn't you use that for a BackgroundWorker"

Answer (score 1):

The other option to `Thread.Sleep` would be `Task.Delay` for the task way of accomplishing the same.

See [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You're my hero and my savior. Thank you very much! <3

Comment: I am currently experiencing a situation where my background worker simply ends if I execute: await Task.Delay(200);

No error is thrown whatsoever.